# Authenticate in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

when setup mongodb, i has been created admin account:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "demo",
    pwd: "demo",
    roles:
    [
      {
        role: "userAdminAnyDatabase",
        db: "admin"
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

but when connection database using java:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("mydb");
String username = "demo";
String password = "demo";
boolean auth = db.authenticate(username, password.toCharArray());
System.out.println(auth);
```

result false, somebody can help me???

Answer (score 0):

See the link for procedure of authentication done in mongodb [Enable Client Authentication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/), may be you missed the first step, hope it helps you.